# How to configure HTTPS on more than one port on JBoss Fuse 6.3

Tags: ssl, https, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

Im trying to enable HTTPS on more than one port in JBoss Fuse 6.3
How can i achieve this.

I have follow the below tutorial to enable HTTPS on 8443.
https://fusemiddleware.wordpress.com/2015/04/12/generate-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool/

Need to enable the HTTPS on 8443 and 9192 port on JBoss Fuse 6.3

Is there any other way to achieve this. I need to enable https on 8443 and also on 9192 port.

Im using Apache Camel, Apache CXF and JBoss Fuse 6.3

Answer (score 0):

I would say that's not possible to use OSGi managed(OSGi http service) ssl port, only one(by default 8443) is possible here. However if it's CXF endpoint you can use httpj:engine-factory[1] to configure an embedded jetty server with any SSL port you wanna use, though this is not recommended way in OSGi container, in OSGi you should always use OSGi http service IMO.

[1]http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jetty-configuration.html